# How to calculate the best performing stock in a historical data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, stock

I have a stock database looks like this

**Stock**

`date, symbol , open , close , low , volume`

The data are something like this

```
{
 "date":"05/01/16 00:00",
 "symbol":"WLTW",
 "open":"123.43",
 "close":125.839996,
 "low":122.309998,
 "high":126.25,
 "volume":2163600
}
```

I have been given to write a query in mongodb to get the best performing stock .

```
const getBestPrice = (data) => {
    console.log('Hitting Symbol Model fine!!')

    return Stock.find()
        .then((symbol) => {
            console.log(symbol)
            if (symbol) { return symbol }
        })
}
```

I am using Mongoose for ORM

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What did you mean by best performing, you will have to define two days in order to do that, which is initial investment and the end date. Please be more specific

Comment: @JanithKasun that's what even I am confused, they did not mention that in the question, So I am assuming since its a history data, so the end date would be today and start date would be the last data from the db

Comment: how do you define the best performing if you have two date range? it would be helpful to give an example here to write an aggregation.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment you should be doing it yourself :)